# How can you prevent Formsauthentication to block css and images?

Tags: asp.net, css, image, forms-authentication

I have a project containing an image, css and js folder.
I want to make sure no css, image or js is blocked when using formsauthentication.

I know you can do this with the locationtag in the web.config but I was wondering if you could do this otherweise?

this is how I do it right now:

```
<location path="css">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

I'm using asp.net (c#) with iis 7.0.

Cheers,
M.

Comment: Please refer previous answer.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686613/asp-net-forms-authentication-prevents-loading-javascript-on-login-aspx][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686613/asp-net-forms-authentication-prevents-loading-javascript-on-login-aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the folder permissions for your CSS/images directories, to allows anonymous access.

This is done in the web.config, not filesystem permissions.

Comment: yeah, I know that's what I mentioned in the question. but I wanted to know if there was any other way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [good practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) to serve static resources such as images and css from a cookie-free domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeking the same answer however in my case it is allowing access to CSS, Images and JS files by default. I think it only requires authentication if for ASPX (etc).

Also, I am using deny users "?" rather than "*"