# ASP.NET Forms Authentication prevents loading javascript on Login.aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I am experiencing problems with Forms Authentication. When I try to load my Login.aspx page neither javascript nor stylesheets do not load.
Here is part of my web.config file

```
        <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
               timeout="30"
               name=".ASPXAUTH"
               path="/"
               requireSSL="false"
               slidingExpiration="true"
               defaultUrl="Main.aspx"
               cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Help me, please, to understand what's happening.

Comment: I suspect that your problem of not loading javascript and CSS is not related to forms authentication. What does FireBug say about those static resources?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add exceptions to those directories or files in your web.config, underneath the `<configuration>` element.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     ...
  </system.web>

  <location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594/css-not-being-applied-on-non-authenticated-asp-net-page

Answer (score 0):

Put in Global.asax

```
Public Sub FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As FormsAuthenticationEventArgs)
    If args.Context.Request.Path.EndsWith("js") Or args.Context.Request.Path.EndsWith("css") Then
        Dim ObjUser As WindowsIdentity = args.Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity
        Dim ObjPrincipal As WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(ObjUser)
        args.User = ObjPrincipal
    End If
End Sub
```