# JavaScript error in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I use Spry.Widget.Accordion (Dreamweaver CS5) in my ASP.NET web site, When I use ASP.NET Form Authentication, I receive this error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Accordion1 = new Spry.Widget.Accordion("Accordion1");
</script>
```

> Error: Microsoft JScript run time error: 'Spry' is undefined.

Comment: Could it be this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686613/asp-net-forms-authentication-prevents-loading-javascript-on-login-aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not including the spry library. are you sure you did that?