# Ignoring a file extension to be authenticated

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, iis-6, forms-authentication

I implemented [this code](http://robertpohl.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/cached-javascript-minification-on-fly.html) to compress JS files from my site at runtime.

But now all my JS files redirect to login page.

If I add this to web.config:

```
  <location path="asd.js" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

The JS file opens normally. But I do not want to do this for every JS file from my site.

How to make any JS requires authentication?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to put all of your "ignore" files in a certain directory, then add an exception for that entire directory in your path. See below for a similar question and solution:

[ASP.NET Forms Authentication prevents loading javascript on Login.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686613/asp-net-forms-authentication-prevents-loading-javascript-on-login-aspx)

```
<location path="scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```